# How to design a microservice application which depends on multiple legacy services?

Tags: architecture

I am designing a transformation solution for an e-commerce application that depends on some legacy services. It is supposed to be a microservice application which will get new microservices, but how to manage (use) legacy services with a guarantee of performance?
Legacy services are built of java5 and .NET Framework 4.0 and are 8-9 years old.

Answer (score 0):

I suppose your new microservice application will consume existing legacy services not mix with them. So they will be accessed via http or some amqp messaging protocol. As the general rule not to mix environments you can provide stable autoscaling for old services, create proxy for them in order to get common interface, handling of errors, provide load balancing and consume services through that. When old services are down for some reason you can create additional queue that will store temp data for them and after they are back - you can process it async. In that way there is an option also to decorate with additional functionality.